# Can I change the font for a part of a static text?

Tags: wxpython

I know that I can set the font with "SetFont()", but this only works for a whole static text. I have something like this (doesn't work, just as example):

```
sports = ['football', 'baseball', 'basketball']
for i in range(3):
    wx.StaticText(self.mypanel, -1, sports[i].SetFont(anyfont) + ' is great!', (50,50+20*i))
```

So in all these 3 displayed sentences only the first word shall receive the font; 'is great!' mustn't receive the font. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the StaticText widget doesn't support that. You could use a border-less read-only (or disabled) TextCtrl in Rich Text mode to do it though. If you don't have it already, download the wxPython demo package. It has an example of changing the font for certain words in it. Alternatively, you could also you HTMLWindow.

Comment: Thank you, I could solve it with a TextCtrl. Indeed, there is a border around my text, but this is no problem for me.

Comment: There's also a style flag you can use to remove the border. I think it's wx.NO_BORDER. Or see this fun thread on rolling your own control: http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/Borderless-textbox-revisited-td2338666.html

Answer (score 0):

You could put "is great!" into a different static text control. If you used sizers it would be pretty easy to get it to line up and look like a single static text